# Dropdown based on another dropdown in jsp Struts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, struts-1

I'm very new to Ajax. Currently I'm working on a new project. For that project one of the requirements is, populating a second dropdown based on the input from the first dropdown. I'm using Struts to do that. I don't want the page to be refreshed, so I need to use Ajax for calling the second dropdown content in the backend and populate in the second dropdown. I don't know how to write code for that.

What should be included (jars,tags) in my struts project?
What entries should come in my JSP (I am using `<html:select>`)?
What will come in JavaScript?
What will come in action class (in action class I can fetch the list values from the DB based on the selection from the first dropdown)?

Comment: What did you try? Did you ever start to write a code?

Comment: I tried initially with sumitting form. but its resetting all the previous values. i have around 45 fields. Its very difficult to keep all values in request. So I'm looking for Ajax. I have seen couple of examples. but I wasn't able to corelate my code with those examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of ajax, I used struts only to acheive this. I have assigned all variables to form to keep values when submitting form.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question would probably a thesis ;) 
I will just guide you in here.

1]Use a javascript framework like jquery. It will help you make ajax calls to your controller URL 
Check an easy tutorial on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-ajax.htm

2] For the controllers lets have two urls mapped:

- urapp/poplateDropdown1  to controller which return values/list target at ur first drop down
- urapp/poplateDropdown2 to a another controller(or method within same controller) which responds to a GET request and receives a parameter say name SEL_VALUE for the selected value.

3] onchange events. 
Have an onchange or similar best suited even on your first dropdoww. 
In your event call a js function; like `<select onchange=callDropDown2Controller(this.value) >`
in your callDropDown2Controller() method:

```
//pseudo implementation
callDropDown2Controller(var selectedValue){

// now generate an AJAX get request using jquery with the following url 
urlToCall =  '/urapp/poplateDropdown2?SEL_VALUE=' + selectedValue

}
```

The rest buddy u need to do some homework and research.

Comment: I really appreciate your quick help. I will try my best and let you know.